# wifi connection changed action in android

Tags: android, android-wifi

i want to start my application when wifi will be turn on so that i try get action for wifi state changed function
but it showing

```
01-27 15:52:10.470: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(11584): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.WiFiScanReceiver: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.WiFiScanReceiver
```

this is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light">
    <activity android:name=".WiFiDemo" android:label="@string/app_name">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.example.WiFiScanReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
  </application>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

[i fallow this link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/40.html) guide me how to start my activity when wifi is turn on.

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WiFiDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
 private static final String TAG = "WiFiDemo";
 WifiManager wifi;
 BroadcastReceiver receiver;

 TextView textStatus;
 Button buttonScan;

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  // Setup UI
  textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
  buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
  buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);

  // Setup WiFi
  wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

  // Get WiFi status
  WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
  textStatus.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());

  // List available networks
  List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
  for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
   textStatus.append("\n\n" + config.toString());
  }
  
  // Register Broadcast Receiver
  if (receiver == null)
   receiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(this);

  registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
    WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
  Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
 }

 @Override
 public void onStop() {
  super.onStart();
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
 }

 public void onClick(View view) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "On Click Clicked. Toast to that!!!",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonScan) {
   Log.d(TAG, "onClick() wifi.startScan()");
   wifi.startScan();
  }
 }

}
```

here is my BroadcastReceiver code

```
package com.example;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class WiFiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
  private static final String TAG = "WiFiScanReceiver";
  WiFiDemo wifiDemo;

  public WiFiScanReceiver(WiFiDemo wifiDemo) {
    super();
    this.wifiDemo = wifiDemo;
  }

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    List<ScanResult> results = wifiDemo.wifi.getScanResults();
    ScanResult bestSignal = null;
 final String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
   System.out.println("booladsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");
  
  }
    for (ScanResult result : results) {
      if (bestSignal == null
          || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, result.level) < 0)
        bestSignal = result;
    }

    String message = String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest.",
        results.size(), bestSignal.SSID);
    Toast.makeText(wifiDemo, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() message: " + message);
  }

}
```

Comment: Please post the source of your WiFiDemo Activity.  I am guessing that there is no broadcast receiver registered.  But, I can't tell unless you post the source. :)

Comment: @Jonathan now i update my code..

Comment: Thanks, I posted an answer which suggests that you move your BroadcastReceiver implementation into an anonymous class.  Then you will not need to worry about passing the reference to the WiFiDemo Activity.

Answer (score 2):

Your receiver class does not have a default constructor. Only a constructor that requires a `WiFiDemo` so android cannot figure out how to make an instance of that class.

Update:
I think you have been a bit confused on how broadcast receivers work. There are two ways:

1. You describe it in you xml and Android will instance the object when the event happens - in this case you need a default constructor e.g. `public MyReceiver() {}` instead of `public MyReceiver(MyObject obj) {}`
2. You register your broadcast receiver in code. This type can have any constructor.

So to solve you issue. Just remove the deceleration of the broadcast receiver in your manifest.

Comment: thank you for your comment can you please explain me via code. thank you in advance..

Comment: @user1105375 Ok, read the complete code now and the tutorial you followed. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android will not be able to instantiate that class because the constructor requires a WiFiDemo.

Why not just make your broadcast receiver anonymous?

```
    package com.example;

    import java.util.List;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
    import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class WiFiDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
     private static final String TAG = "WiFiDemo";
     WifiManager wifi;
     BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
         @Override
         public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();
            ScanResult bestSignal = null;
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)) {
               System.out.println("booladsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss");

            }
            for (ScanResult result : results) {
                 if (bestSignal == null || WifiManager.compareSignalLevel(bestSignal.level, result.level) < 0)
                      bestSignal = result;
            }

             String message = String.format("%s networks found. %s is the strongest.",
             results.size(), bestSignal.SSID);
             Toast.makeText(wifiDemo, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() message: " + message);
         }

     };

     TextView textStatus;
     Button buttonScan;

     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);

      // Setup UI
      textStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textStatus);
      buttonScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
      buttonScan.setOnClickListener(this);

      // Setup WiFi
      wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

      // Get WiFi status
      WifiInfo info = wifi.getConnectionInfo();
      textStatus.append("\n\nWiFi Status: " + info.toString());

      // List available networks
      List<WifiConfiguration> configs = wifi.getConfiguredNetworks();
      for (WifiConfiguration config : configs) {
       textStatus.append("\n\n" + config.toString());
      }

      // Register Broadcast Receiver        
      registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
        WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
      Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
     }

     @Override
     public void onStop() {
      super.onStart();
      unregisterReceiver(receiver);
     }

     public void onClick(View view) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "On Click Clicked. Toast to that!!!",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      if (view.getId() == R.id.buttonScan) {
       Log.d(TAG, "onClick() wifi.startScan()");
       wifi.startScan();
      }
     }

    }
```

Comment: again face same error 01-27 18:03:26.500: E/AndroidRuntime(19704): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.WiFiDemo: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.WiFiDemo cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver

Comment: Found the error, remove: `if (receiver == null) receiver = new WiFiScanReceiver(this);`

Comment: please tell me wether manifest files are right or not now i change question manifest.

Comment: 01-27 18:38:30.380: E/AndroidRuntime(24278): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.WiFiDemo: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.WiFiDemo cannot be cast to android.content.BroadcastReceiver